# JScrollPane not showing on JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to get a JScrollPane to appear on my JTable. I passed the table to the scrollpane when i created an instance of the component. But to no avail it has yet to show on my table.

```
 table = new JTable();
 scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
 table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
```

I dont know how i can fix this issue, i cant seem to find an issue that would cause it to fail. Here is the rest of the GUI code. It is very long. Adding the jtable to a jpanel starts at line 152.

```
  /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javasql;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author KJ4CC
 */
public class UserInterface implements ActionListener {

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);

    public UserInterface() {
        startGui();
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Javasql sql = new Javasql();
    JPanel buttom = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel commandPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel label = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JButton connect = new JButton("Connect To Database");
    JButton clr = new JButton("Clear Command");
    JButton exeSql = new JButton("Execute SQL Command");
    JButton clrRes = new JButton("Clear Result Window");

    JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel("Enter Database Information ");
    JLabel driverLabel = new JLabel("JDBC Driver: ");
    JLabel dbLabel = new JLabel("Database URL: ");
    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username:  ");
    JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
    JLabel sqlLabel = new JLabel("Enter SQL Command: ");
    JLabel connectionLabel = new JLabel("No Connection Now ");
    JLabel exeLabel = new JLabel("SQL Execution Result: ");
    //creating an instance of the new table
    public JTable table;
    public JScrollPane scrollPane;

    JComboBox driverSelect = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox url = new JComboBox();

    JTextField username = new JTextField();
    JTextField pass = new JTextField();
    JTextArea command = new JTextArea(1, 1);

    public void startGui() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        System.out.println("sdf");
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10);
        c.fill = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        //adding all of the compoenets to their panel and then to the frame.
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        top.add(infoLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        top.add(driverLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.ipadx = 150;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        top.add(driverSelect, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill = 0;

        top.add(dbLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        top.add(url, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill = 0;
        c.fill = 0;
        top.add(userLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        top.add(username, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.fill = 0;
        c.fill = 0;
        top.add(passLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        top.add(pass, c);
        //add the driver and url to the comboboxes
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        commandPane.add(sqlLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.ipadx = 150;
        c.ipady = 75;       //sql text area for command 
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        commandPane.add(command, c);

        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 20);

        c.ipadx = 9;
        c.ipady = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        //buttons
        label.add(connectionLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        //c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 50);

        buttons.add(connect, c);
        connect.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 2;
        buttons.add(clr, c);
        clr.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 3;
        buttons.add(exeSql, c);
        exeSql.addActionListener(this);
        //adding the label and buttons above and below the tabel. 
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        buttom.add(exeLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------Table here 
        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        buttom.add(table, c);
        buttom.add(scrollPane);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        buttom.add(clrRes, c);

        c.weightx = 2;
        c.weighty = 2;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        frame.add(top);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(commandPane);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(buttons);

        frame.add(buttom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //adding the content panel to the jframe. 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(1000, 550);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //adding items to both of the combo boxes. 
        driverSelect.addItem("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        url.addItem("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project3");

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == connect) {

            sql.connect(this);
        } else if (e.getSource() == clr) {
            command.setText("");

        } else if (e.getSource() == exeSql) {
            sql.exeCommand(this);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    buttom.add(table, c);
    buttom.add(scrollPane);
```

here you add the table twice, directly in the first line and (implicitly) along with the ScrollPane at the last line.

In Swing this is not possible. Therefore the JTable is removed from the Scrollpane at the first line, when you add it directly to the `bottom` panel, and in turn at the last line an empty scrollpane is added, removing the JTable added earlier.

just remove the first line.

Comment: ok this worked. I removed the buttom.add(table,c ) and replaced it with the  scrollpane addition and it works!

Comment: _"and replaced it with the scrollpane addition"_ you already had it in the last  line I copied from your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can not add the table twice :

```
    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);   //here
    table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    buttom.add(table, c);                  //here
    buttom.add(scrollPane);
```

If you add it to the scrollPane, just add the scrollpane. A Component can't have two parents.

I did not check your complete code but try

```
    buttom.add(scrollPane,c);
```

instead of this

```
    buttom.add(table, c);                  //here
    buttom.add(scrollPane);
```